# How do I configure Leprechaun field/type mapping at a feature level?

Tags: helix, code-generation

I've added the below configuration to a `CodeGen.config` file at the Feature level. The code is generated and put into the feature `Template.cs` file, but the mapping I've added isn't picked up. If I add the `fieldType` mapping to the `<shared><metadataGenerator...` node in Leprechaun.config, the type is correctly output.

```
<configuration name="Feature.Multimedia" extends="MyProject.Base">
  <metadataGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTemplateMetadataGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true">
    <fieldType id="{0D16C6F0-0FE9-4F06-8073-31802BC73D17}" type="custom=MyProject.Foundation.Theme.ColorItem" />
  </metadataGenerator>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: use xWrap https://github.com/vhil/xWrap :)